# Formula to get the worked hours from time A to time B where B is past midnight

Tags: excel, time

I'm using Excel to write down my shifts and get a total of worked hours per day and per week.

I structured it this way:

[image: excel worksheet structure]

Everything seemed to work fine until I finished to work at 12.30 am. The result with my formula was -17 hours instead of 7. How can I fix my formula so that it displays a correct amount? I'm using the following formula and I want the result to be displayed in number format, not time.

`=IF(C11=0,0,IFERROR(((C11-B11)-D11)*24,0))`

What formula can I use?

Comment: Try adding AM/PM as mentioned in this article: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Add-or-subtract-units-of-time-9a6558a1-a86b-41d4-b244-1000fc7d31e9?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA Also check the formatting of the cell for unit type

Comment: Thanks guys but I've found a different solution using MOD function. Works as supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Excel treats days as 1 for every day past Dec 31, 1899. Today happens to be 42,217. Time is nothing more than a decimal portion of a day. Today at noon was 42,217.5 and tomorrow at 03:00 will be 42,218.125.

Excel also treats boolean (e.g. TRUE/FALSE) values as either 1 or 0 when used in a mathematical equation. e.g. 0.5 + TRUE = 1.5 while 0.5 + FALSE = 0.5.

Test to see if the [minuend](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_subtrahend_and_a_minuend) is less than the [subtrahend](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_subtrahend_and_a_minuend) and if it is, add 1 to it using the result of the test itself.

```
=(C11+(C11<B11)-B11)*24
```

[image: Time Across Midnight]

Finally, it should be mentioned that while you can subtract a larger time from a smaller time to receive a negative decimal value, the negative value cannot be interpreted as time since Excel does not recognize negative time. If you were not multiplying by 24 to retrieve the hours as integers and simply subtracting B11 from C11 the cell would be filled with hashmarks (e.g. ############) to show the error. e.g. 08:00 - 10:00 = (as time) #######.

Comment: Thanks guys but I've found a different solution using MOD function. Works as supposed to.